# Error: Sonar Qube Code Coverage report path not found in Azure pipeline

Tags: android, kotlin, sonarqube, azure-pipelines, code-coverage

I am getting error in Azure pipeline for sonar qube code coverage report. In local its building the report but in pipeline its not able to find path. Below is error:

No coverage report can be found with sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='C:\agentDevOps1_work\3490\s\Samplelogic\build/reports/jacoco/codeCoverageReport()codeCoverageReport.xml'. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml

Below is code i used to give path in local and its working in local and generating the report successfully.

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.java.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes"
            property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "${project.buildDir}/reports/jacoco/codeCoverageReport/codeCoverageReport.xml"
            property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "${project.buildDir}/test-results/testDevDebugUnitTest"
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/build/jacoco/testDevDebugUnitTest.exec"
            property "sonar.kotlin.binaries", "${project.buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes"
        }
    }
```

Azure pipeline is configured for window machine. I am using mac machine as local. Dont know what path to give to fix this error. Can anyone suggest solution to fix this error?

Comment: When you write that you don't know which path to give to fix this, do you know what the path is? If so, I think you should add it to the question so that it can be more easily compared with your configuration. And for the error message specifically: Sonar can be a little picky about these, but this error message never lied to me (as you can read from that, I nevertheless experienced it my own as wel). So my guess is that this is a configuration error, paths need to match. Windows should take slashes and backslashes as the same, so IIRC this is not the culprit in case you wondered.

Comment: I assume that you are probably using [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines) to run the sonar analysis in your Azure pipeline. Bash does not like the `:` or the `\\` in a given path. You can use the [CmdLine task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to run the sonar analysis. Although, I am not entirely sure what's the main cause of this error. You may need to provide the pipeline snippet if possible.